# Working Asynchronously with GUI Controls in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, asynchronous, delegates, callback

I have a listbox of items that need to be processed, and I would like to process them asynchronously on a separate thread. (Never done this before).

So I created a Delegate, a Callback, called the method that does the work on the listbox items.

I am getting an exception "System.InvalidOperationException": 
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ListBoxBlah' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Doing the asynchronous operation for individual items doesn't make sense to me because I am only doing it to perhaps perform a large number of operations (the listbox may have 20000 items) in the background while allowing the user to do other stuff.

To interact with GUI this must become more complicated... I just don't know how:

```
Public Sub F(ByVal ext As String)
    If ListBoxBlah.SelectedIndex = -1 Then Return
    'Process ListBoxBlah
End Sub

Delegate Sub E(ByVal ext As String)

Sub Callback(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim t As E = CType(CType(ar, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult).AsyncDelegate, E)
    t.EndInvoke(ar)
End Sub

Public Sub Ex()
    Dim t As E = AddressOf F
    t.BeginInvoke("ext", AddressOf Callback, "state")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "processed"?  Does the user add and remove items from the listbox?  Should they be allowed to do so while "processing" is happening?  Does the "processing" need to be made aware of changes to the listbox data or does it simply need to work with a snapshot of the data?

Comment: When you say you have a listbox of items I assume you want to take that list (e.g a list of product numbers) and do something in the background yes? If so look at BackgroundWorker process. It's the best for beginner wanting to do Async work http://bit.ly/320a66

Comment: They need to work with the selected items, no add or remove - but they need full access to the selected items (like file path) (and that list has a tendency to refresh or use the items on threads that are not mine)

Comment: I feel that a few key points are still unclear :  1) Where does the data in the ListBox come from?  2)  When does the ListBox get updated and how?  3)  When does "processing" need to be done?  4) Can (or should) the ListBox be updated (or updateable) while "processing" is happening?  5) Does "processing" need to be informed if the ListBox contents have changed while it is "processing"?

Answer (score 2):

In c# when you want to access the GUI from a thread that didn't create the GUI you use "Invoke required"
I assume that in VB.NET it's the same.
try this : http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/database-general-discussion/19740-how-use-invokerequired.html